# "There is no code editor for MainWindow.xaml" error in Blend 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blend

I am only getting the following error in Blend for Visual Studio 2019, when clicking on "View Code" after right-clicking in the designer view:

> There is no editor available for MainWindow.xaml. Make sure the application for the file type (.xaml) is installed.

- I can open each file individually (i.e. the designer and the code-behind)
- This error does not occur in Visual Studio 2019, but in Blend
- This happens for multiple project files
- I've repaired VS with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling Xamarin